# MainBar is Obsolete Active Reports

Tags: c#, activereports

I'm working in `ActiveReports` **Version 7.0** in which, when i customize the `ToolBar` i'm getting a warning.

//Code

```
ReportViewer.Toolbar.MainBar.Items.RemoveAt(2);
```

**Warning:**

```
GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.Viewer.ViewerToolbar.MainBar' is obsolete: Use ToolStrip property instead
```

Where am i supposed to use the `ToolStrip` property? Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for using [ActiveReports](http://activereports.grapecity.com/)

Here is the [viewer customization](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#CustomizetheViewerControl.html) topic 
and list of toolbar items [here](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#WindowsFormsViewerCustomization.html)

Toolstrip is a member of the [viewer toolbar](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.v10~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.Viewer+ViewerToolbar.html)

To access it use `viewer1.Toolbar.Toolstrip` and it returns a standard windows forms Toolstrip instance.

Hope this helps.